# Is/will the AMD Radeon HD 6650M be supported?

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati

I have a discrete AMD Radeon HD 6650M graphic card.

I can't run it, whether with the free `radeon` driver and `vga_switcheroo` nor with `fglrx` and `sudo aticonfig --px-dgpu`.

Will Ubuntu support this graphic card soon?

Comment: Your card is supported, as available drivers and works under Ubuntu. What do you mean with cant run?

Comment: I have hybrid graphics. When i change to discrete Radeon with vga_switcheroo then X server doesn't restart and i cant go to console with Strg + Alt + F1. With fglrx driver and aticonfig --px-dgpu i get segmentation fault on restarting X. Using oneiric.

Comment: Discrete means ATI only right? Did you change to discrete before before installing Ubuntu? You want to use only ATI or are you trying to enable the hybrid solution?

Comment: I have no BIOS option to change to discrete, i can just use switchable graphics. The ATI is the discrete one. And the integrated is Intel

Comment: tell your laptop model (all the numbers and letters plz)

Comment: LENOVO G770 M533DGE

Comment: I also have Dell Vostro 3550 with radeon 6630m. I can't use a catalyst driver becouse i have a segmentation fault on restarting X. This is annoying. Catalyst driver wrote "aticonfig: No supported adaptaters detected"